# How to make my Personal laptop as Web hosting Server for my Website?

Tags: web, web-hosting

How to make my Personal laptop as Web hosting Server for my Website?
I am well versed with WAMP, XAMP with other technologies But don't know how to run my website on my own server and can be accessible to everyone.

Comment: The very nature of “mobile” computer is that it is mobile. So, I’m assuming you realize the laptop will become a permanent fixture on your desk if you plan to host a 24x7 website on it? With that said, it is no different than hosting a website on a desktop or server computer and requires an understanding of multiple subjects. This question is too broad to answer in a single post. Please do some research and ask a more specific question.

Comment: be aware that most home internet plans are still asynchronous in nature, giving you much faster download than upload. Unfortunately for visitors to your server, their download is your upload, hence sloooow